# Alcoholic beverage brought by groom as a gift to bride's family

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm naturally an Estonian and we have a word called "kosjaviin" and it's a noun. In general it is a bottle of strong alcohol (~40%) brought by groom as a gift to the bride's family. The first part of the word means "betroth" and the other part means "vodka". In Estonia it is a traditional gift to the future in-laws on the day the groom pops the question.

My question is: "Does there exist a similar word in English?"

Additional questions are welcome!

Comment: Does the same tradition exist in any English speaking part of the world? If not I doubt there will be any such word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an incredibly archaic word, *bridesmead*, but it hasn't had any currency (except as a placename) in hundreds of years. (We did keep the mead month, or *honeymoon*, in the language, but the meaning has changed considerably with changing customs in matrimony.) Distilled spirits weren't "a thing" when the custom was alive; that didn't happen until the 12th century in Europe.